# Two variables concatenated inside single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have went through many samples to have a variable inside quotes..But that doesnt help my case..it is strange in my case..have a look at it..

```
Var x='http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc'

Var y='/logincheck'
```

Now i want to have it inside a single quoted string like

```
'http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck'
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a file named domainname.xml

I get the value http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc from that file.Now i need to concatenate /logincheck with it and pass as an URL to an ajax call...

Thats my specific need guys !!

Any ideas friends ???

Comment: ever tried var z = x + y

Comment: Do you want the single quotes as part of your string (i.e. the first and last character?)

Comment: I have a seperate file named domainname.xml

I get the value http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc from that file.Now i need to concatenate /logincheck with it and pass as an URL to an ajax call...

Thats my specific need guys !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between a variable declared with single quotes vs. one declared with double quotes:

```
var a = 'test';
var b = "test";
a === b;
> true
```

To join your two strings, just concatenate them with a `+` or `concat()`:

```
var x='http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc';
var y='/logincheck';

var z = x + y; // concat with +    
z;
> "http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck"

// or

var z = x.concat(y); // concat with contact()
z;
> "http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck"
```

---

Now, if we're all just misunderstanding your question, and what you are actually looking for  is a string with single quotes as part of the string contents, here's how you can get that:

```
var x='http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc';
var y='/logincheck';
var z = "'" + x + y + "'"; // use double quotes as string delimiters
// or:
var z = '\'' + x + y + '\''; // use single quotes as delimiters and
                           // escape the single quote in the string
z;
> "'http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck'"
```

Comment: 'http://www.xyzftp.com/myservice/Service1.svc''/updateversion'

THIS IS MY RESULT FOR THE ABVE COMAND...

But what i wanted is like 

'http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck'

Comment: Where did the "updateversion" come from? Can you copy and paste your actual code in the question? It sounds like there's a typo or something else going on.

Comment: 'xyzftp.com/myservice/Service1.svc''/logincheck'; 

THIS IS MY RESULT FOR THE ABVE COMAND... But what i wanted is like

 'xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck';

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
Var x='http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc'

Var y='/logincheck'

x= x+""+y;  or simply x= x+y;
```

you will get string: 'http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck'

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 'http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc';
var y = '/logincheck';
var combined = x + y;
```